# Python scale down numbers in xml file

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have an xml file with point coordinate like this

```
<vertex x="15" y="15.2"/>
```

I would like to scale these coordinate like

```
<vertex x="15*factor" y="15.2*factor"/>
```

with `factor=0.2` (a number)

I was thinking about using `re`. Something like:

```
 re.sub(r'(x=\"[0-9]\"', X, X*factor, data)
```

I prefer not two loop over all lines, and `split` and so one...

since I'm reading the file as one string

```
f = open(filename)
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

## EDIT:

More context

```
<polygon>
    <vertex x="-15" y="15"/>
    <vertex x="-15" y="-15"/>
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="15" y="-15"/>
    <vertex x="15" y="15"/>
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="-15" y="-15"/>
    <vertex x="15" y="-15"/>
</polygon>
```

*Output for factor=0.1*

```
<polygon>
    <vertex x="-1.5" y="1.5"/>
    <vertex x="-1.5" y="-1.5"/>
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="1.5" y="-1.5"/>
    <vertex x="1.5" y="1.5"/>
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="-1.5" y="-1.5"/>
    <vertex x="1.5" y="-1.5"/>
</polygon>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *I prefer not to loop over all lines* - How else do you plan to process the file?

Comment: why such a format `data=<>` ? Post more context with expected xml structure

Comment: sorry, no data. typo.

Comment: @0x5453  I edited my answer. I just `read` the file at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<r><polygon>
    <vertex x="-15" y="15"/>
    <vertex x="-15" y="-15"/>
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="15" y="-15"/>
    <vertex x="15" y="15"/>
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="-15" y="-15"/>
    <vertex x="15" y="-15"/>
</polygon></r>'''


def scale(factor):
    root = ET.fromstring(xml)
    vertex_lst = root.findall('.//vertex')
    for vertex in vertex_lst:
        for attr in ['x','y']:
            vertex.attrib[attr] = str(int(vertex.attrib[attr]) * factor)
    ET.dump(root)


scale(0.1)
```

output

```
<r><polygon>
    <vertex x="-1.5" y="1.5" />
    <vertex x="-1.5" y="-1.5" />
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="1.5" y="-1.5" />
    <vertex x="1.5" y="1.5" />
</polygon>
<polygon>
    <vertex x="-1.5" y="-1.5" />
    <vertex x="1.5" y="-1.5" />
</polygon></r>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what might be desired output here, my guess is maybe we would start with an expression similar to:

```
(x=|y=)\"\s*([-]?[0-9]+)\s*\"
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(x=|y=)\"\s*([-]?[0-9]+)\s*\""

test_str = ("<polygon>\n"
    "    <vertex x=\"-15\" y=\"15\"/>\n"
    "    <vertex x=\"-15\" y=\"-15\"/>\n"
    "</polygon>\n"
    "<polygon>\n"
    "    <vertex x=\"15\" y=\"-15\"/>\n"
    "    <vertex x=\"15\" y=\"15\"/>\n"
    "</polygon>\n"
    "<polygon>\n"
    "    <vertex x=\"-15\" y=\"-15\"/>\n"
    "    <vertex x=\"15\" y=\"-15\"/>\n"
    "</polygon>")

subst = "\\1\"\\2\\*factor\""

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/t5ARjO/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

Comment: That's nearly what I'm looking for. However, it seems that the *calculation* (number times factor) can not be performed, right? See my edit.

Comment: You might reconsider parsing [x|html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451).

Comment: @Emma although your answer is not exactly not what I wanted, but I thought it has great value. I learned some nice regex-stuff there. Thank you!